# Calendar.Events.delete isn't there in google app script Calendar v3

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

According to: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#methods, there is a delete method. Instead, I only find a remove method. I understand the difference is that remove only takes the event off that specific calendar, whereas delete takes it off any calendar it was on. So what happened to delete? Is the documentation wrong and the remove method is the replacement with option arguments to handle various cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`delete` is a reserved word in JavaScript so it is common best practice not to use it as a method name or property of an object.

The optional params of `.remove()` allow you to specify whether attendees are notified or not.

In any case it is removing the event from the calendar in which it is hosted which will perform the delete. This maps how it works in the Google Calendar UI.

Comment: Thanks Jonathon. So to confirm, it is a documentation error?

Comment: There is no error in documentation. The links to Calendar API are just that and `delete` is the method and works in other libraries. Apps Script documentation doesn't replicate the API documentation but admittedly it could be clearer in its deviation in this instance. Many of the advanced services suffer a similar deficit.